# Chrome Cordova Translation Issue

Tags: ios, google-chrome, cordova, google-chrome-app

Im trying to translate my chrome app to ios. I run the command cca create myapp --copy-from=manifest.json Some errors exist cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENAMETOOLONG): $PATH_TO_PROJECT/project/platforms/ios/www/platform/..../www/platform/config.xml
where .... is 40 repeated directories of /www/platform

The translation succeeds and im able to run my project with android however, when trying to run in xcode i see an almost identical error saying File name too long.

Anyone have simmilar issues? Anyone able to get ios translations to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of a bug in the way we "import" your project when you specify `--copy-from` or `--link-to` arguments to `cca create` when your import directory is the same as your output directory.

Since the import in your example is a parent folder of the output, it copies itself over and over, recursively until the system kills the process.  We have added protection against doing this (by warning during `cca create` if we detect this case), but that version hasn't released to `npm` just yet (sorry!).

The fix for the issue is simple: just create your project in another directory that is outside of your packaged app!  i.e., either:

```
# From within packaged app directory
cca create ../myapp --copy-from=./manifest.json
```

or

```
# From outside packaged app directory
cca create myapp --copy-from=$APP_DIR/manifest.json
```